# Is it possible to run a script only if a certain button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

I only want my javascript to run if a certain button is pressed, how do I do this?

Would it mean I would also have to keep my javascript in a seperate file and bring it in on a click?

Comment: it doesn't _have_ to be in a separate file (although that is recommended) but you _would_ have to bind that function to some sort of event handler.

Comment: You mean like in [this "Hello World" example?](http://webdesignfromscratch.com/javascript/js101/) This tutorial shows everything from making a button with an inline click event to activating a function that resides in a separate file.

Comment: Yes, you can use events with javascript. What you are looking for is the click event.

Comment: You want to bind to the button's `onclick` event.

Comment: Of course it's possible. How else would JS run in response to user interaction? Consider running through some tutorials in order to learn the basics. [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Just use this on your button to execute a function:

```
<button onclick="functionToExec()">Click me!</button>
```

If you don't have a function, you can create one with this code:

```
<script>
function functionToExec() {
alert("You clicked!"); // Just an example
}
</script>
```

Just put all the code you need to run in the middle part, between the curly braces.
Make sure that the code is on the same page, or in a js file that you will make care of including.

> "Okay thanks, I think what I meant to say was, how do I make my script
>   inactive unless a button is pressed? My script targets certain buttons
>   and records the clicks and times of the click. But I don't want that
>   to run unless a 'start' button is pressed"

You'll need to insert your script in a js file and then include it on the fly.

Here's how you do it:

```
var htmlHeader = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var myScript = document.createElement('script');
myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
myScript.src = 'myscriptlocation.js';
htmlHeader.appendChild(myScript);
```

Just put this code in the curly braces, editing the location of your script (can be relative or absolute).

Comment: Okay thanks, I think what I meant to say was, how do I make my script inactive unless a button is pressed?
My script targets certain buttons and records the clicks and times of the click. But I don't want that to run unless a 'start' button is pressed

Comment: See the edit, tell me if it's ok.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me, it seems like the javascript isn't being loaded in for whatever reason.
Could I not use a boolean?

Comment: Yes, you can use it, but you would need to check if the variable is true with a timer or with object.watch that is not a standard.
However, you can see here the code working: [link](http://jsbin.com/modevaye/1/edit?html,js,console,output) It includes a js file from my site (ignore the errors, they are there because of my js file) when the button is clicked.

Comment: Under network in the google chrome inspect element tool it's telling me that my .js file is being loaded in, but it doesn't seem to work once it's in there

Comment: That's weird... on Firefox the js gets loaded and executed. I'll try tomorrow with different browser if it's ok for you.

Comment: It is, I disabled Adblock and I tried doing it on Firefox and it was doing the same.
The js works fine when it's inside the html file but that way it will execute automatically when I need it to activate to a button.

Comment: Also tried with Jquery using getScript() with no luck either.
Still appears to load in the script but doesn't work.
Maybe it has something to do with my code?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/modevaye/2/edit?html,js,console,output
Hi, i've tried with a proper script, and it works! Can you please test it in other browsers? I have a slow connection and i can't download much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You also use jquery's .click function.
http://api.jquery.com/click/